# XRDP - Status of CVE-2020-4044

Tags: 20.04, xrdp

It's been more than 9 months since Ubuntu released a security note about the CVE-2020-4044 (https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2020-4044)

In this note, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) is still noted as "needed" about the security patch release by the editor.

Why the patch is still not applied and when it will ? The priority is Medium (7.8) and the editor indicate that the version must be updated. I can't find any information about an update, can you help me see more clearly ?

Thanks.
Dylan

Answer (score 3):

XRDP is in the Universe component of Ubuntu, which is *not* regularly guaranteed security updates because Universe is community-supported.

The Security team only patches Universe-packages when there's a community backer who wants to do the prep work of getting the patch in, testing the patch, make sure it builds on all versions of Ubuntu, etc.

Until someone from the Community steps up to handle all the work and provide the product of that work to the Security team for consideration, it won't get patched.

Security Team is only going to guarantee patches for Main components of the repos - not for Universe.

---

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories lists the different 'components'/pockets of Ubuntu and what they each mean - Main is canonical supported software, Universe is community supported.